# How do I query a property with a dot in it?

Tags: mongodb

Generally, MongoDB doesn't let one have dots in property names. For example:

```
db.books.insert({"protagonist.name": "Guy Montog"});
```

fails with the error:

```
uncaught exception: can't have . in field names [protagonist.name]
```

However, I ran across a situation in which property names do have dots. This can occur in the system.profile collection. Here's an example:

```
db.setProfilingLevel(2);
db.books.insert({protagonist: "Guy Montog", antecedents: 
  [{title: "The Fireman"}, {title: "Bright Phoenix"}]});
db.books.find({"antecedents.title": "The Fireman"})
```

Now If I look at the system.profile collection, I see the following record:

```
> db.system.profile.findOne({op: "query"})
{
    "ts" : ISODate("2012-10-14T00:05:49.896Z"),
    "op" : "query",
    "ns" : "wordswing.books",
    "query" : {
        "antecedents.title" : "The Fireman"
    },
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nreturned" : 1,
    "responseLength" : 153,
    "millis" : 0,
    "client" : "127.0.0.1",
    "user" : ""
}
```

Suppose I wanted to query the for system.profile documents that queried "antecedents.title"? This seems to be a problem because there is a dot in the property name.

I tried all of the following:

```
db.system.profile.find({'query.antecedents.title': 'The Fireman'})
db.system.profile.find({'query.antecedents\.title': 'The Fireman'})
db.system.profile.find({"query.antecedents\.title": 'The Fireman'})
```

None of which worked.

Ideas?

This is really interfering with my ability to poke around a rather large system.profile collection.

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

In response to a comment, the version I'm using is:

```
$ mongod --version
db version v2.0.6, pdfile version 4.5
Sun Oct 14 18:43:29 git version: e1c0cbc25863f6356aa4e31375add7bb49fb05bc
```

Kevin

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The profile entry for the dotted query does appear to be a bug .. [key names](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Legal+Key+Names) in MongoDB are not meant to include `.` (or a leading `$`).

As you've noticed, this will cause you issues when trying to query because the [dot notation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29) is used to indicate embedded objects.

A limited workaround in MongoDB 2.2.0 appears to be using the Aggregation Framework to match the query object as an embedded document:

```
db.system.profile.aggregate({ $match: {'query': {"antecedents.title" : "The Fireman"}}})
```

I've reported this profiling bug in MongoDB's issue tracker as [SERVER-7349](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7349).